# Несколько имён у одного PHP скрипта

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть задача. На сервер есть следующая логическая структура:

- /cal/001.php
- /cal/002.php
- ...
- /cal/nnn.php

В реальности же структура файлов нужна такая:

- /cal/script.php

Что хочу. Пользователь вызывает скрипт по логической структуре (например 002.php), однако происходит запуск скрипта script.php с переданным параметром в виде имени файла (002.php или 002, без разницы тут). Как такое реализовать?

Проблема в том что логических имён слишком много и обновление динамическое.

Comment: смотрите https://web-optimizator.com/chpu-htaccess/ и прочие ресурсы по запросу в гугл "htaccess чпу"

Answer (score -2):

Используйте `htcaccess` (если у вас апач) примерно следующим образом.

```
RewriteRule ^cal/(\d{3})\.php  script.php?p=$1  [L, QSA]
```

значения `001` и т.п. будете получать в `$_GET['p']`.